# In Ant, how can I dynamically build a property that references a property file?

Tags: ant

I am using Input tasks to collect specific property values and I want to concatenate those into one property value that references my properties file.

I can generate the format of the property but at runtime it is treated as a string and not a property reference.

Example properties file:

```
# build.properties

# Some Server Credentials
west.1.server = TaPwxOsa
west.2.server = DQmCIizF
east.1.server = ZCTgqq9A
```

Example build file:

```
<property file="build.properties"/>
<target name="login">
 <input message="Enter Location:" addproperty="loc" />      
 <input message="Enter Sandbox:" addproperty="box" />
 <property name="token" value="\$\{${loc}.${box}.server}" />
 <echo message="${token}"/>
</target>
```

When I call login and provide "west" and "1" for the input values, echo will print ${west.1.server} but it will not retrieve the property value from the properties file.

If I hardcode the property value in the message:

```
<echo message="${west.1.server}"/>
```

then Ant will dutifully retrieve the string from the properties file.

How can I get Ant to accept the dynamically generated property value and treat it as a property to be retrieved from the properties file?

Comment: See Ant Faq for building a new property upon existing properties => http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#propertyvalue-as-name-for-property Ian's answer uses the hack mentioned in the propertycopy macrodef.

Comment: See https://github.com/apache/ant-antlibs-props for the sources of props antlib - the build.xml does not work though, but the ../antunit folder has some examples to get you going. Here's one possible download => http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/ant-props/ant-props-1.0Alpha.jar.zip - otherwise search internet for that jar or use nexus. Props antlib works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the great links, that FAQ is exactly the solution, grabbed the .jar from the download and got the nested properties working as desired!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additional example using the [Props antlib](http://ant.apache.org/antlibs/props/).
Needs Ant >= 1.8.0 (works fine with latest Ant version 1.9.4)
and Props antlib binaries.

The current build.xml in official [Props antlib GIT Repository](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=ant-antlibs-props.git;a=summary) (or [here](https://github.com/apache/ant-antlibs-props)) doesn't work out of the box :

```
BUILD FAILED
Target "compile" does not exist in the project "props".
```

Get the sources of [props antlib](https://github.com/apache/ant-antlibs-props/archive/master.zip) and unpack in filesystem.
Get the sources of [antlibs-common](https://github.com/apache/ant-antlibs-common/archive/master.zip) and unpack contents to ../ant-antlibs-props-master/common
Run `ant antlib` for building the jar :

```
[jar] Building jar: c:\area51\ant-antlibs-props-master\build\lib\ant-props-1.0Alpha.jar
```

Otherwise get the binaries from [MVNRepository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.kuali.common/kuali-antprops/1.0.1-alpha) or [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/ant-props/ant-props-1.0Alpha.jar.zip)

The examples in [../antunit](https://github.com/apache/ant-antlibs-props/tree/master/src/tests/antunit) are quite helpful.
For nested properties look in [nested-test.xml](https://github.com/apache/ant-antlibs-props/blob/master/src/tests/antunit/nested-test.xml)

Put the ant-props.jar on ant classpath.

```
<project xmlns:props="antlib:org.apache.ant.props">

 <!-- Activate Props antlib -->
 <propertyhelper>
   <props:nested/>
 </propertyhelper>

 <property file="build.properties"/>

 <input message="Enter Location:" addproperty="loc" />      
 <input message="Enter Sandbox:" addproperty="box" />
 <property name="token" value="${${loc}.${box}.server}"/>

 <echo message="${token}"/>

</project>
```

output :

```
Buildfile: c:\area51\ant\tryme.xml
    [input] Enter Location:
west
    [input] Enter Sandbox:
1
     [echo] TaPwxOsa

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 4 seconds
```

Answer (score 7):

The [props antlib](http://ant.apache.org/antlibs/props/index.html) provides support for this but as far as I know there's no binary release available yet so you have to build it from source.

An alternative approach would be to use a `macrodef`:

```
<macrodef name="setToken">
  <attribute name="loc"/>
  <attribute name="box"/>
  <sequential>
    <property name="token" value="${@{loc}.@{box}.server}" />
  </sequential>
</macrodef>
<setToken loc="${loc}" box="${box}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution is :**
Consider problem is this, where you want to achieve this :

```
<property name="prop" value="${${anotherprop}}"/> (double expanding the property)?
```

You can use javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
    propname = project.getProperty("anotherprop");
    project.setNewProperty("prop", propname);
</script>
```

I gave it a try and this is working for me.